# How to create dynamic trigger with stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I am working on an audit trail using SQL Server triggers to identify inserts, updates and deletes on tables. Below are my tables and trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditTrail]
(
   [AuditId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [DateTime] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
   [TableName] [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
   [AuditEntry] [XML] NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditTrail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
   [ID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
   [NameEmployee] [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction]
(
   [ID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
   [NameTransaction] [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Transaction] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)

CREATE TRIGGER AuditEmployee 
ON [dbo].[Employee]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) > 0 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @AuditMessage XML
        SET @AuditMessage = (SELECT * FROM deleted FOR XML AUTO) 

        INSERT INTO AuditTrail (DateTime, TableName, AuditEntry)  
        VALUES (GETDATE(), 'Simple', @AuditMessage)
    END
END
GO
```

I have created a trigger for the employee table, but that is a static trigger. How to dynamically trigger with stored procedure depends on the number of tables we have, except the `AuditTrail` table?

Comment: "how to dynamically trigger with storeprocedure". What does this mean? If you insert data into this table via a Stored Procedure, why would it not fire the trigger? The one caveat would be the CURSORS sent in if a batch statement sent many modifications in at once, however, it seems like you are accounting for that in your "deleted" loop.

Comment: You don't. Every time you create a table you also create the trigger that implements your auditing goals. You do not have sufficient skill to write/implement dynamic skill and I would argue that this is a case where it is not needed.